# how to enable httponly for jsessionid cookie in jboss 4.2.3

Tags: cookies, jsessionid, jboss-4.2.x, httponly

how to enable httponly for jsessionid cookie in jboss 4.2.3 ?

Note :jboss 4.2.3 is having implementation of servlet 2.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't... 
For the same kind of requirement,  I had to patch tomcat class.

in tomcat's org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.java

you can add this kind of properties by changing code on the `appendCookieValue` method (you can also check on witch cookie you want to apply this ... )